# MySQL Replace string from one character to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I am dealing with string paths with have an array index in them, indicated by [#] where # is the index. This index can be anything. What I am trying to do is to in my path string, remove all the [#] occurrences. So brackets and anything within brackets to be removed. I see the replace function but I am not sure how to use an arbitrary “middle” between the brackets to replace.

I want to remove from `'['` to `']'` and replace this with `''`.

Ex path: `Number[2].padding[1]` reduced to `Number.padding`.

Right now I have something like :

```
replace(path, '[%]', '')
```

Where I'm trying to use `%` as a wildcard, but it is not functioning.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: I’m not sure which one you are pointing to. I know about replace and I’ve thought along the lines of a substring, but I can’t seem to find one that can specify from one character to another character

Comment: You could always try REGEX

Comment: How deep can the paths be?

Comment: they can be "infinitely" deep

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to capture parts of string like `[#]` as follows

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(@txt, '\\[[^]]*\\]', '');
```

Regexp breakdown :

```
\\[      # opening square bracket
[^]]*    # 0 to N characters other than a closing square bracket 
\\]      # closing square bracket
```

Example with your test data :

```
SET @txt = 'Number[2].padding[1] reduced to Number.padding';
SELECT @txt input, REGEXP_REPLACE(@txt, '\\[[^]]*\\]', '') output

| input                                          | output                                   |
| ---------------------------------------------- | ---------------------------------------- |
| Number[2].padding[1] reduced to Number.padding | Number.padding reduced to Number.padding |
```

Comment: Great answer. Similar to what I figured out but a much better detailed answer with output. Also I didn't know about the carrot so that could've had consequences. Thank you!

Comment: it seems that I am not using MySQL 8.0 afterall. Is there a way to do this without REGEXP_REPLACE?

Comment: I am trying get the array brackets and text out of a path so I can compare to my parameter variable path.

Comment: @C.Programming ...  without `REGEXP_REPLACE`, this will probably be painful... Question : is this always a one-digit number that is within the brackets, or it may be more than one digit ?

Comment: there may be more than one digit

Comment: I could theoretically do this in my app but it sounds expensive having to query for all the paths, then doing the replacing on all of them, then finally doing string comparisons. I am trying to update the rows that match this comparison so then I would also have to concatenate a list of ids to update in the db. This is why I thought I could easily do so in the SQL.

Comment: @C.Programming : I understand... Are you able to upgrade to MySQL 8.0, where `REGEXP_REPLACE()` is available ?

Comment: I cannot upgrade to 8.0 it seems.